# Can Applescript send get or post requests?

Tags: php, macos, get, applescript

I use Hazel to organize downloaded files on my Mac. I see i can make it run applescripts every time it triggers a rule.

I was wondering if it is possible to make it send something like:

http://my.server.com?type=Show&name=Big+Bang+Theory

Then i could create a small page that logs all downloads.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, the command line utility curl is one way. Applescripts can use command line utilities with the "do shell script" command. So try this...

```
set theURL to "http://my.server.com?type=Show&name=Big+Bang+Theory"
do shell script "curl " & quoted form of theURL
```

The above will return the page results to applescript. Maybe you'd rather just open the link in your default browser...

```
set theURL to "http://my.server.com?type=Show&name=Big+Bang+Theory"
open location theURL
```

So take your pick!

Comment: Thank you very much, i think i can work from this. So what ever my php file outputs will bee returned to the applescript in the first example? How can i use the returned output?